# How do I rectify XAMPP Apache blocked ports and missing dependencies overriden with another XAMPP version

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I have an old XAMPP ver3.2.2 installed on my system which I have been using to manage some never deployed joomla and wordpress sites. Apache and MySQL ports got blocked perhaps due to some newly installed softwares. Out of intense frustration to get it fixed quickly, I reinstalled another XAMPP found on my system which I tagged XAMPP-1 during installation. This time, it was ver5.6.15, I thought it was the same version as the installed - Failed to check the version. Well, I copied the apache folder from it and replaced the old apache. Now things have gone weirder. Apache and MYSQL gives no sign of showing up again. I intend upgrading to the latest version that supports PHP 7, but then I have to login to backup my files. Really lost and confused here. I understand it was a dump move on my side. Any help would be much appreciated. Moreover, XAMPP 3.2.2 isn't found online anymore, or could I be missing something.?

Below is the message from XAMPP

```
8:49:53 AM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
8:49:53 AM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
8:49:54 AM  [Apache]    Autostart active: starting...
8:49:54 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache service...
8:50:03 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
8:50:40 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
8:50:40 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
8:50:40 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:50:40 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:50:40 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
8:50:40 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:50:40 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
8:50:40 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Look for `datadir` in my.cnf file and copy that folder. No old Xampp version should run when a new installation is done. Ensure they are stopped and removed from autostart. Move them to a backup folder. Make a clean installation.

Comment: You can start any installation using something like `\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --datadir=\path\to\your\backup` on the command line.

Comment: Most likely IIS is using port 80 on Windows 10. You can netstat from xampp control panel and open the service manager as well. Locate some service like "WWW Publishing Service" and set the start type not to startup automatically.

Comment: Thanks Quasimodo's clone. I have the feeling this will work, but how do I access my.cnf file? my site installations are in htdocs folder.

Comment: Since this seems to become more complex I've formed a complete answer. Get back if there is something unclear. `my.cnf` is named `my.ini` within the `bin` dir on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should manage complete new installation of XAMPP, a recent version is recommendable.

First make sure no old XAMPP is running and none is starting on Windows startup. Move your old installations into a backup folder. After a restart your system services should be clean.

You can start `netstat` from within the xampp control panel. Look for services using port 80 and/or 143. On Windows 10 systems most likely the IIS uses those ports. Start the service manager which is also startable from within the control panel. You might find some service named 'WWW Publishing Service' or similar, that is IIS. You can use the search function function in the service manager, look for 'WWW'.

If there is one, right-click and open properties. Set a start type not starting automatically. Check netstat after a reboot. The ports should be free now.

Download the most recent (or, if for some reason desired, a specific) version from the originial [Apache Friends site](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html). Do the installation process with default settings.

You can start mysql from the command line using a specific data folder with the command

```
\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --datadir=\path\to\your\backup\mysql\data
```

The data folder can be found in the `mysql\bin\my.ini` file in the `datadir =` line, typically `"C:/xampp/mysql/data"` (that's the old location before moving of course). You should make a backup copy of the data folder before accessing it with a new version. `mysqldump` should support the `--datadir` option as well.

You can try to replace the mysql data folder of the new installation, but do not overwrite it, stop the mysql service and rename the current folder into some backup name before doing so. However, I would prefer to use a clean installation and import old databases.